# Conditionally setting properties from a selection

Tags: ant

I've created an ant task that will deploy to a specific url, and it works fine.
However I'd like to use the same task again to deploy to a second env. The only difference being in the URL of the env I supply.

I've created two properties in my build.properties :
DEVURL
TESTURL
and I'd like to set the relevant one within my target, based on an argument that I supply. for example build.xml -Denv=DEV would run the target with the URL set to DEVURL.

I've looked at the condition task, but it only seems to set things dependent on the property being set, not the value within the property ?
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself : wasn't using the  correctly.

```
<if>
<equals arg1="${envname}" arg2="DEV"/>
<then>
<echo message="ENV is : DEV"/>
</then>
</if>
```